# Can I host my own travis runner?

Tags: travis-ci

I work on a large open source project based on ruby on rails.  We use Github, Travis, Code Climate and others.  Our test suite takes a long time to run and we have many pull requests opened and updated through the day, which creates a large backlog.  We even implemented a build killer in our bot to prevent any unnecessary builds, however we still have a backlog.  Is it possible for us to host our own runner to increase the number of workers?

Answer (score 0):

There's Travis CI Enterprise (https://enterprise.travis-ci.com/) that lets people host their own runners, but that's probably mostly only for paid-for customers. Have you guys swapped over to the container-based builds? Might speed things up a bit. What's the project?